# regex - test for exactly 1 number and exactly 2 letters

Tags: regex

Please assist me with creating this regex.

```
A total/exactly 3 digit alphanumeric
Exactly 1 numeric excluding 0 and 1   2-9
Exactly 2 Alpha excluding letter O and L - o and l
Number can be in any position
```

**Valid codes:**

```
A2M
HH9
3AM
```

**Invalid Codes**

```
10M (too many digits and invalid digits, 
22A (two many digits), 
MAB   (missing digit)
MA2M  (too long, not length of 3)
```

thank you for all the help. Here is the regex I will use, this one removes the letter `L` and lowercase `l`:

```
/([2-9]{1}[A-KMNP-Za-kmnp-z]{2}|[A-KMNP-Za-kmnp-z]{1}[2-9]{1}[A-KMNP-Za-kmnp-z]{1}|[A-KMNP-Za-kmnp-z]{2}[2-9]{1})/g
```

Comment: Jeez, try `(?i)^(?=.*[a-kmnp-z].*[a-kmnp-z])(?=.*[2-9])[a-kmnp-z2-9]{3}$` or yuio can try `Reference - What does this regex mean?` give yuio a 1 in 5.78 million odds to find an anser. .. dupr supr

Comment: what @anubhava asking Jesus if he knows regex ? and if he says no ?

Comment: Yes, I attempted to write the regex but hoped I would get assistance from someone that had expertise rather than links to learn-on-your-own pages. I searched Stack Overflow and did not find exactly what I needed.
Here is what I have come up with so far. It does the job but isn't very eligant
/([2-9]{1}[A-MNP-Za-mnp-z]{2}|[A-MNP-Za-mnp-z]{1}[2-9]{1}[A-MNP-Za-mnp-z]{1}|[A-MNP-Za-mnp-z]{2}[2-9]{1})/g

Comment: The regex is for users to enter a specific code they receive via email to access an operation. They could receive a phone call as well and we didn't want people misreading the code.   Numbers are stripped that could be misinterpreted as letters  Zero "0"  and letters that could be mistaken for numbers   l L 1 and the letter O o.

Comment: You may expect that any regex written for this problem will have mucho  repetition of character classes. As an aside, if your regex engine supports [subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) you can shorten the regex and reduce the chances of making errors in those portions of the expression that would otherwise be repeated See [ref](https://regex101.com/r/hOnD3g/1/) for a straightforward solution that uses subroutines with the PCRE regex engine.

Comment: thank you for all the help.  Here is the regex I will use, this one removes the letter L and lowercase L "l".      /([2-9]{1}[A-KMNP-Za-kmnp-z]{2}|[A-KMNP-Za-kmnp-z]{1}[2-9]{1}[A-KMNP-Za-kmnp-z]{1}|[A-KMNP-Za-kmnp-z]{2}[2-9]{1})/g

Comment: Further to my last comment, if you prefer you can used named capture groups with subroutines. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/hOnD3g/2/).

Comment: @JesusIsComing: You can post an answer below using that regex to your own question.

Comment: This still needs details and clarity. As instructed in the [`regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info), you need tn specify which regex variant or tool you are using (PHP maybe?) and the regex looks like you are trying to find multiple matches in a line; is that correct? A regex to find each code isolated alone on a line will be simpler than one to find word tokens matching this pattern in running text (and then begs the question how exactly you define a word).

Comment: There are many similar questions about password validation (minimum lengthtX characters, needs to contain at least Y characters of category Z and V characters of category W, etc) but most of them are for regex variants which allow for lookaheads, which are not a standard feature in basic regex. Still, have a look at those, too (if only to see how to successfully ask a well-defined question).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to shorten your regex with use of a lookahead:

```
^(?=\D*\d\D*$)[A-KMNP-Za-kmnp-z2-9]{3}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cUtjMH/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=\D*\d\D*$)`: Lookahead to ensure that we have exactly one digit
- `[A-KMNP-Za-kmnp-z2-9]{3}`: Match any letter or digit except `[01LlOo]` exactly 3 times
- `$`: End